# Can't create new data when I create relations between tables in database in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created two model classes (`Company` and `Location`) in my ASP.NET Core project and created controllers with views using Entity Framework. Then I added migration and updated database. Everything worked just fine (CRUD) until I've tried to create a relations (using foreign keys).

When I added this line of code in my `Location` model:

```
public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
```

I couldn't create new locations anymore. Same for the companies when I added these lines:

```
public int LocationId { get; set; }
public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
```

I have 0 errors, but nothing happens when I click on `Create` button.

My models look like this:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {
    }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public Location()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What `Create` button? Is this a button in your application? If so, what does the implementation look like?

Comment: Did you update the database after you add the relationship? Did you debug your method if it goes to the update line?